# Cache entire website in chrome app

Tags: webview, google-chrome-app, browser-cache, kiosk-mode

I am making a chrome app.  It is for a kiosk type application.  At times the computer will be offline when it starts up.  So I'm looking to make an application that a user can navigate to a website and then the entire website is cached.  Then when they turn on the Chromebox/Chromebook the website will come up as it was.  Including JS/CSS/dynamically loaded content.

Overall I'm looking to save the state of the entire webview and have it keep going after the machine reboots.  I looked into saving the JS/CSS/HTML but then the dynamically loaded content (ajax calls) is not available.  Is there a higher level function for saving the ENTIRE state of the webview in a google chrome app?

Answer (score 0):

[Zebradog's Kiosk Chrome App](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kiosk/afhcomalholahplbjhnmahkoekoijban) recently added "Serve local content" support. It works by using [Web Server for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb) in the background. It loads the content in a webview. You may not want a whole kiosk app, but this could at least be a starting point for you to use as reference.

One way of actually getting all the files, if you don't have them already, would be to use `wget -r -k`